# Backend Order listing page extremely slow

Tags: magento-1.9, database

When navigating to backend order listing page, the site is extremely slow and takes about more than 30mins before displaying the order info.

Looking at `show full processlist` on mysql, it looks like this query is causing the slow down:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `temp_sales_order_items`.*, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`company` AS `shipping_company`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`street` AS `shipping_street`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`city` AS `shipping_city`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`region` AS `shipping_region`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`country_id` AS `shipping_country_id`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`postcode` AS `shipping_postcode`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`telephone` AS `shipping_telephone`, `temp_shipment_grid`.*, `temp_shipment_track`.*, `order_payment_tbl`.`method`, `temp_sales_order_comments`.*, `temp_sales_order`.* FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT `sales_flat_order_item`.`order_id`, `sales_flat_order_item`.`parent_item_id`, GROUP_CONCAT(`name` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `product_names`, GROUP_CONCAT(`sku` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `skus`, GROUP_CONCAT(`product_id` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `product_ids`, GROUP_CONCAT(`product_options` SEPARATOR '^') AS `product_options`, SUM(`qty_refunded`) AS `total_qty_refunded`, SUM(`qty_ordered`) AS `total_qty_ordered_aggregated`, SUM(`qty_canceled`) AS `total_qty_canceled`, SUM(`qty_invoiced`) AS `total_qty_invoiced` FROM `sales_flat_order_item` GROUP BY `order_id`) AS `temp_sales_order_items` ON `main_table`.`entity_id` = `temp_sales_order_items`.`order_id` AND `temp_sales_order_items`.`parent_item_id` IS NULL
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `order_address_shipping_tbl` ON main_table.entity_id = order_address_shipping_tbl.parent_id AND order_address_shipping_tbl.`address_type` = "shipping"
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT (IF(IFNULL(`entity_id`, 0)>0, 1, 0)) AS `shipped`, SUM(`total_qty`) AS `total_qty_shipped`, `sales_flat_shipment_grid`.`order_id` AS `shipment_order_id` FROM `sales_flat_shipment_grid` GROUP BY `shipment_order_id`) AS `temp_shipment_grid` ON `main_table`.`entity_id` = `temp_shipment_grid`.`shipment_order_id`
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`track_number` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `tracking_number`, `sales_flat_shipment_track`.`parent_id` AS `tracking_parent_id`, `sales_flat_shipment_track`.`order_id` AS `tracking_order_id` FROM `sales_flat_shipment_track` GROUP BY `tracking_order_id`) AS `temp_shipment_track` ON `main_table`.`entity_id` = `temp_shipment_track`.`tracking_order_id`
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_payment` AS `order_payment_tbl` ON `main_table`.`entity_id` = `order_payment_tbl`.`parent_id`
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`comment` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `order_comment`, `sales_flat_order_status_history`.`parent_id` AS `comment_parent_id` FROM `sales_flat_order_status_history` GROUP BY `comment_parent_id`) AS `temp_sales_order_comments` ON `main_table`.`entity_id` = `temp_sales_order_comments`.`comment_parent_id`
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT `sales_flat_order`.`subtotal`, `sales_flat_order`.`base_subtotal`, `sales_flat_order`.`shipping_amount`, `sales_flat_order`.`base_shipping_amount`, `sales_flat_order`.`entity_id` AS `temp_entity_id` FROM `sales_flat_order` GROUP BY `entity_id`) AS `temp_sales_order` ON `main_table`.`entity_id` = `temp_sales_order`.`temp_entity_id` WHERE (main_table.order_group_id = '0') ORDER BY main_table.created_at DESC LIMIT 20
```

I have installed Extended Orders extension (http://www.mageworx.com/extended-orders-magento-extension.html). Other than that, I haven't done any other customization.

Looks like an inefficient query or missing indexes but I can't debug it myself. Anyhelp is much appreciated.

`Explain` results as below:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                           | type  | possible_keys                          | key                                           | key_len | ref                             | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | main_table                      | ALL   | NULL                                   | NULL                                          | NULL    | NULL                            | 15552 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>                      | ALL   | NULL                                   | NULL                                          | NULL    | NULL                            | 17923 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | order_address_shipping_tbl      | ref   | IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ADDRESS_PARENT_ID | IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ADDRESS_PARENT_ID        | 5       | magento_19.main_table.entity_id |     1 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>                      | ALL   | NULL                                   | NULL                                          | NULL    | NULL                            |  4849 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived4>                      | ALL   | NULL                                   | NULL                                          | NULL    | NULL                            |  4830 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | order_payment_tbl               | ref   | IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_PAYMENT_PARENT_ID | IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_PAYMENT_PARENT_ID        | 4       | magento_19.main_table.entity_id |     1 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived5>                      | ALL   | NULL                                   | NULL                                          | NULL    | NULL                            | 17923 |                                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived6>                      | ALL   | NULL                                   | NULL                                          | NULL    | NULL                            | 17918 |                                              |
|  6 | DERIVED     | sales_flat_order                | index | NULL                                   | PRIMARY                                       | 4       | NULL                            | 18631 |                                              |
|  5 | DERIVED     | sales_flat_order_status_history | index | NULL                                   | IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_STATUS_HISTORY_PARENT_ID | 4       | NULL                            | 60711 |                                              |
|  4 | DERIVED     | sales_flat_shipment_track       | index | NULL                                   | IDX_SALES_FLAT_SHIPMENT_TRACK_ORDER_ID        | 4       | NULL                            |  4885 |                                              |
|  3 | DERIVED     | sales_flat_shipment_grid        | index | NULL                                   | IDX_SALES_FLAT_SHIPMENT_GRID_ORDER_ID         | 4       | NULL                            |  4697 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | sales_flat_order_item           | index | NULL                                   | IDX_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ITEM_ORDER_ID            | 4       | NULL                            | 73325 |                                              |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
13 rows in set, 9458 warnings (0.50 sec)
```

Comment: You mention the extended orders extention. Does the issue remain if you disable that extension?

Comment: Did you found a way to reduce the loadtime? I have the same problem with my orders grid (take ages to load...)

Answer (score 3):

Log all of you db queries by setting `$_debug = true;` in `lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php` and this will output all sql query to `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log`.

You will get idea about how many queries are running and which one taking how much time.
Do not enable this to production environment.

Hope this will help you.